# Load function between AJAX and Wordpress doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, jquery

I can't get the content from a div (width a specific ID) from single.php into index.php with ajax.
Now I have this code and returns "0".

```
$("body").on("click", 'a.loadcontent', function() { 
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var slug = $(this).data('slug');
});
function loadcontent(type,id,slug, action) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url:srvars.ajaxurl, 
        data: { 
            action:'sr_get_content', 
            id:id, 
            type:type
        }, 
        success: function(response) {}
    });
}
```

and from functions.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_sr_get_content', 'loadAjaxPosts');
add_action('wp_ajax_sr_get_content', 'loadAjaxPosts');
function loadAjaxPosts() { 
    switch($_REQUEST['type']) {
        case 'portfolio':
            $output = sf_portfolio_items($_REQUEST['cat'], $_REQUEST['count'], $_REQUEST['page'], true);
        break;
        case 'blog':
            $output = sf_blog_items($_REQUEST['cat'], $_REQUEST['count'], $_REQUEST['page'], true);
        break;
        default:
            $output = 'Incorrect type specified, please contact support.';
        break;

    }
    $output=json_encode($output);
    if(is_array($output)) {
        print_r($output);   
    } else {
        echo $output;
    }
    die;    
}
```

How to transfer the content?
Thanks

Comment: I am not seeing where you are calling `loadcontent`.

Comment: I have that part too..

Answer (score 0):

I have that part too..

```
$("body").on("click", 'a.loadcontent', function() { 
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    var type = $(this).data('type');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var slug = $(this).data('slug');

    if(window.location.hash.substr(1) == slug) { 
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: 0}, animationSpeed, $easingType);
    } else {
        window.location.hash = slug;    // set the hash
        //history.pushState({page:href}, href, href);
        loadcontent(type,id,slug,false);
    }

    return(false);
});
```